# Is there a recommended way to update NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I'm currently using 6.0.4, I'd like to get to 6.5.2.  What is the best way to do this?  Is there something in the CLI?  Do I manually update each @nestjs package?

Current dependencies are:

```
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^6.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.0.2",
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the Nest CLI to update the dependencies:

```
$ npm install -g @nestjs/cli
$ nest update
```

You can also `$ nest u`

As Mick mentioned in his comment, you might have to add `--force`
argument.

```
nest update --force
```

## Update - July 7 2022

Since [v9.0.0 release](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/9588), the command `update` was removed.
To upgrade your dependencies, you can use dedicated tools like [ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates), npm update, [yarn upgrade-interactive](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade-interactive), etc.

Comment: This didnt do anything for me (had 6.x and wanted 7.x) but `nest update --force` does an **upgrade**.

Comment: I had an old version of the cli installed - had to upgrade that by rerunning `npm install -g @nestjs/cli` before nest update would work properly

Comment: doesnt work. Just sits there saying installation in progress.

Comment: If you are here, to upgrade nestjs9, use `ncu` because `nest update` is deprecated in nestjs9.

Answer (score 34):

Force update with the command:

```
nest update -f -t latest

nest info 



_   _             _      ___  _____  _____  _     _____
| \ | |           | |    |_  |/  ___|/  __ \| |   |_   _|
|  \| |  ___  ___ | |_     | |\ `--. | /  \/| |     | |
| . ` | / _ \/ __|| __|    | | `--. \| |    | |     | |
| |\  ||  __/\__ \| |_ /\__/ //\__/ /| \__/\| |_____| |_
\_| \_/ \___||___/ \__|\____/ \____/  \____/\_____/\___/


[System Information]
OS Version     : macOS Catalina
NodeJS Version : v12.16.1
NPM Version    : 6.13.4
[Nest Information]
platform-express version : 7.4.2
microservices version    : 7.4.2
common version           : 7.4.2
core version             : 7.4.2
```

You can check at this [post](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/321#issuecomment-506646369)

[Nest Docs: nest update](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-update)

Comment: just reporting that I used it to upgrade nest 8 to 9 and worked fine.

Comment: @BrunoLamps impossible, in nest9 nest update is deprecated.

Comment: But if you try to upgrade nest 8, the command will be there, right? I did it last month ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 17):

I followed this [answer](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1204#issuecomment-927705971)

```
npm install -g @nestjs/cli
npx npm-check-updates "/nestjs*/" -u
```

Comment: This suggestion can fix the same problem on my machine.

Answer (score 10):

The `nest update` command has been deprecated. The NestJS creator now recommends using the `npm-check-updates` package.

### Using NPM

Install the `npm-check-updates` package:

```
npm i npm-check-updates
```

Now update the NestJS related packages:

```
npx ncu -u -f "/nestjs*/"
```

This command will update only the dependencies that have `nestjs` in their name in `package.json`

Then run:

```
npm install
```

After running the app, if you get the error: `Cannot find module...`

Install the packages manually one by one with the following commands:

```
npm i @nestjs/config

npm i @nestjs/jwt

npm i @nestjs/platform-express

npm i @nestjs/core

npm i @nestjs/common

npm i @nestjs/typeorm --force
```

### Using Yarn

Install the `npm-check-updates` package:

```
yarn add npm-check-updates
```

Update the NestJS packages:

```
yarn npm-check-updates -u -f "/nestjs*/"
```

Then, to install the dependencies, simply run:

```
yarn
```

Answer (score 6):

The way I handle this is to manually update each package. It's a little tedious but it gives you full control of what versions each package is set at.

I will usually create a "feature" branch in git, something like `feature/upgrade` where I'll update the packages

```
npm i @nestjs/common@latest @nestjs/core@latest ...
```

Try it out there, then merge that branch into master (or whatever your development branch is). Git removes the need for "copying" code from another directory, if the new package versions breaks something, you have time to fix them in the feature branch before rolling out to production.

Answer (score 4):

### An answer for fast developers:

1. `npx nest update -f`
2. Follow [docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide) link to apply the changes required for the new version

Answer (score 3):

from v9 to v10, you may use ncu for package check

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u -f /^@nestjs/
```

but it won't change the package-lock.json, so you have to do npm install again

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

This works to update to version 9:

```
$ npm install -g @nestjs/cli
$ ncu -u
$ npm i
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to upgrade nestjs from x version to 9 that i personnally used and it worked for me is :
delete package-lock.json

delete node_module
run :

```
npm cache clean --force
nvm i 16.13.0
nvm use default 16.13.0
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm i
```

nestjs 9 use typeorm 0.3
You should update your files (Repository) check this:
https://typeorm.io/changelog

Answer (score 0):

Everything you want to know about upgrading with npm: [NPM Upgrading](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

The best way to do a whole version upgrade in my experience is to install the version you want in a directory, say server/nestjs7, and then copy your code from the earlier version to the new one.  Then just boot from inside /nestjs7 and you are good to go.  Nice to have a fall back to the old version sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I think actually the best solution is to use install `npm-check` and run `npm-check -u`. I have currently updated in that way from 8 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

How I upgraded from 8 to 9 with `yarn`:

- install `yarn add npm-check-updates`
- then execute `ncu u`

Successfully updated in my case.