# How to enable NestJs swagger 4.x plugin

Tags: nestjs

How do you use the new swagger plugin? I  have it in my compiler options:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger/plugin"]
  }
```

And I am running the application with `nest start` as described: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#migration-to-40

However, no automated-magic documentation appears to be happening.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your environment with a basic est ew project with swagger ad I'm rather getting the error:

 Error  "@nestjs/swagger/plugin" plugin could not be found!

Can you please provide your package.json, did you istall the swagger plugin....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It was an issue with global dependencies conflicting with local ones, as well as the old build (set to `incremental` mode) conflicting with the new property generation. Did the following to resolve the issue:

- If nest cli is globally installed, manually upgrade it: `yarn global upgrade upgrade @nestjs/cli`, or with npm (`npm update -g @nestjs/cli`)
- Upgrade local service nest to most recent version: `nest update`
- Add the following to your `nest-cli.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger/plugin"]
  }
```

- Remove your local dist folder (or do a yarn build)
- Start the server with the nest cli commands (i.e. `nest start` or `nest start:dev`)

Comment: Please precise that we should run `nest start` to start the server. I was actually running `npm run start:dev` (which use nodemon) and it was not working. Now everything is OK, thanks !

Comment: I did all the steps, used a file named *.dto.ts, and it's still not working : /

Comment: Very helpful answer, this solved my problem. It works with and without watch-mode for me now.

Comment: Removing the /dist/ folder and starting again solved my problem, with and without the watch flag

Comment: As of now, only `"plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger"]`is necessary.

Comment: after following all the steps, it is still not working for me, can anybody guide me what am i missing here?

Comment: In my case, the issue was that the DTOs were defined in a file whose name did not end with `.dto.ts`.

Comment: Deleting the dist fixed my issue (after successfully wasted hours on it)

Comment: since nest v9.0.0 the nest update command was removed. Alternative ways to update can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512819/16360249

Answer (score 3):

My fix was...

The plugin filters the files it looks up based on a suffix rule.

- If you use a different naming convention than Angular's, you need to pass custom plugin options to fix it;
- If your controller or Dto is not inside a file with the name suffix, it wont be upgraded.

Comment: You just saved me from going crazy, had the DTO inlined for testing... I was close to getting mad.

Answer (score 1):

My fix was:

I changed my filenames to one of the following suffixes: ['.dto.ts', '.entity.ts'] (e.g., create-user.dto.ts)

as described in the document:

https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin

and then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works with:

```
"plugins": [
  "node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/plugin"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

because I've spent hours on this and couldn't find this fix mentioned anywhere:
make sure you install the dependency `reflect-metadata`. that's what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

by adding reflect-metadata I was able to resolve the error ""@nestjs/swagger" plugin is not installed".