# nest-cli @nestjs/swagger plugin don't work

Tags: swagger, nestjs

The "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.0", CLI Plugin isn't annotating all dtos and schemas classes .
nest-cli.json

```js
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["mail/templates/**/*"],
    "watchAssets": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
        "options": {
          "dtoFileNameSuffix": [".dto.ts", ".schema.ts"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried nest build and nest start but .dto.ts remains same

```js
export class BulkUploadDto {
  file: string;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368042/how-to-enable-nestjs-swagger-4-x-plugin

Answer (score 0):

do you know that the plugin won't touch source files, right? you can compare the `.dto.js` with and without the plugin enabled

Answer (score 0):

One more thing I think you should try is deleting your `/dist` folder and then stop and restart the application (`npm run start`) or rebuild. This is a requirement according to the current (V8) [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin#using-the-cli-plugin).

Note that your `.dto` is still missing the comment to be used by swagger.

```
export class BulkUploadDto {
  /**
   * The file to be uploaded
   * @example 'john_doe.jpg'
   */
  file: string;
}
```

Also, there is no need of explicitly setting `.dto.ts` in `dtoFileNameSuffix` option. It is a default.
[image]