# Nest/swagger not found

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

```
 Error "@nestjs/swagger/plugin" plugin could not be found!
```

Have this error while starting my nestjs project. I don't know what am getting wrong. nestjs/swagger package is installed.

Comment: Would this answer be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368042/how-to-enable-nestjs-swagger-4-x-plugin/59376312#59376312

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `@nestjs/swagger/plugin` by `@nestjs/swagger` in your `nest-cli.json`